# Powershell variable not passed into filter

Tags: variables, powershell, filter, foreach

I need to create scirpt which add users from list (containing user Display name) to group
Problem I encountered is :
when I issue command :

```
PS C:\Users\pskwarek> foreach ($a in $csv) {(get-aduser -f "DisplayName -like 'Piotr Skwarek'").samaccountname}
pskwarek
pskwarek
```

but if I use $a variable it doesnt work :

```
PS C:\Users\pskwarek> foreach ($a in $csv) {(get-aduser -f "DisplayName -like '$a.name'").samaccountname}
```

next step I would like to pass it to :

```
Add-adgroupMember -identity "groupname" -member samaccountname
```

but I can't make that single step

edit

```
PS C:\Users\pskwarek> $csv
Name
----
Piotr Skwarek
Renata Skwarek
```

Comment: PS C:\Users\pskwarek> $csv
Name
----
Piotr Skwarek
Renata Skwarek

Answer (score 2):

You need to put $a.name in a subexpression:

```
foreach ($a in $csv) 
{
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -like '$($a.name)'" 
    Add-ADGroupMember groupname -Members $user
}
```

Comment: The syntax of that solution is actually clearer than mine, I always forget about this :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$csv | % { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Groupname" -Member $_.Name  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($a in $csv) 
{
 $sb = [scriptblock]::create("DisplayName -like '*$a*'")
 (get-aduser -f $sb).SamAccountName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($a in $csv) {(get-aduser -f ("DisplayName -like '{0}'" -f $a.name)).samaccountname}
```

You cannot use members of a variable directly in a string as you did.
Using string formatting (the '-f' syntax I proposed) always works.
Another solution would be to use a temporary variable to store $a.name

Comment: I am new to scripting and have to admit I don't get it altough it worked fine thx

Comment: Basically, in PS, you can construct strings and put "placeholders" for variables in them:
`$string = ("This is {0} {1}" -f "my","script")`
This just tells PowerShell to replace {0} by the first element of the list that's placed after '-s', and {1} by the second, and so on.